# How to automatically adjust a range of values to get as close to a target value as possible using only integers

Tags: excel, vba

I have a range of values in Excel that are an output from a series of simple calculations. These values are then entered onto an online system that only accepts integers (yes this is a stupid system, I can't change it). The finance team currently manually adjust the outputs until the total value is as close as they can get it to the correct value with integers, and enter that value. I am wondering if there is an automated way of doing this in VBA. Similar to goal seek but accepting that you might not be able to meet the exact number with integers, just trying to find the closest number. I also need to try to keep the current numbers as close to the 'real' value as possible.

My initial idea was to iterate through each number, try +1 and -1 against each number. Store the output of each, work out which results gives the closest to the answer, stores and repeat. This doesn't feel very efficient though. Any better ideas?

Image 1 below: Number of days is the column of interest. $B/$F = $H. These values need to be integers. The grand total needs to be as close to this value as possible after calculations

[image]

If you round the green values to the nearest whole number, you get a variance to the Grand total.

[image]

Without adjusting the figures by too much from their correct values, how can you work out the combination of figures with the lowest variance to the grand total?

Thanks

Edit: an additional constraint based on the Solver solution below. Must be automatable so its idiot proof (I can do the automation, just hunting for the best methodology)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Solver` is an effective tool for your scenario.

- While it does not guarantee the best solution (minimum variance), the result should be satisfactory.
- You can adjust the offsets in the formulas in columns I and J as required; they represent the lower and upper bounds of rounded days.
- By expanding the range of rounded days, you may potentially achieve a better result, but be aware that it will require more time to run Solver.
- It takes about 90 seconds with the current settings on my PC.

*Microsoft documentation:*

> [Define and solve a problem by using Solver](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/define-and-solve-a-problem-by-using-solver-5d1a388f-079d-43ac-a7eb-f63e45925040?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461)

[image]

[image]

Comment: An excellent solution as I hadn't used solver before and this definitely works...however, one constraint I didn't mention was that I would like to add this to a business level template - so assume it will be used by people that don't know how to use Solver.

Is it possible in VBA so I can then automate it and make it idiot proof?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Summary: Combine jobs that share the same daily rate.  If this is not possible, you're at the optimal (minimum variance) solution.

This is much more of a math question than a programming one, and I'm certainly not able to give a formal proof.  But consider rounding for a moment.  You can either round up, or down.  This means that you can either add the round-up difference to your variance, or you can add the round-down difference to your variance.  Rounding to the nearest integer (as you're currently doing) can also be thought of as *choosing the value that will add the smallest variance to the running total of variances*.  And every time you round a number, the variance will increase.  Therefore, the only way to cut down on the added variance is to reduce the number of times you round.

The only way I can see to achieve this would be to combine the Total Labor Costs of all work that shares the same rate in your calculations.  This will require less rounding, as you now round *once* rather than as many times as individual jobs sharing the same rate.  This will reduce the variance.

Consider the jobs with a daily rate of 233.33.  If you sum the total labor costs of these jobs, you get:

57,441.97

For this calculation, let's just assume this is its own job.  Now, dividing this by the rate of 233.33, you get a Number of Days:

246.18

This rounds to:

246.00 *Note that we've just rounded once for all of those combined jobs!*

Calculating the labor costs based on these rounded values:

(246.00 x 233.3) + (33.00 x 70.6) + (135.00 x 53.7) = 66,971.1

Which has a variance of:

67,063.17 - 66,971.1 = 92.07